# weighted graphs in jave with embedded neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a question about weighted graphs in neo4j. Is a property (like ".setProperty("cost", weight)") the only way of constructing a weighted graph. The problem is that a program, which often needs this weights by "(Double) rel.getProperty("cost")" will get too slow, because the cast takes some time;

Comment: The cost of the cast is negligible compared to other execution time costs.

Comment: Build a proof of concept and measure, if it turns out to become slow there are other ways like the one outlined by Peter below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually could encode the weight into the relationship type which is faster, something like

```
create a-[:`KNOWS_0.34`]->b
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/2dez98 for an example.